# How to write in the middle of a line in an existing file using java?

Tags: java

I hava a .java file that i want to edit using a java program.
Basically I simply want to add an "implement something" after the "class name"

I tried using randomAccessFile that i found on stackoverflow but the problem with it was that it was overwriting the next bytes... How could i simply insert it instead of overwriting the next bytes?

```
    RandomAccessFile f;
    try {
        f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("the path of my file"), "rw");
         f.seek(line.length()-1); // goes to where i want to write
         f.write(name.getBytes()); //writes the string in name
         f.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use RAF as this is not byte data but rather text. Instead simply stream the file, writing as you read, adding in the extra portion where needed.

Comment: If the duplicates above don't help then [search the site for more](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+write+text+in+middle+of+file)

Comment: Consider this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138971/modify-existing-line-in-file-java